# Javascript/css/php/mysql to collect user email addresses in a div on a website

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, webforms, lamp

Suppose you want a box on your website that says "Give us your email address and we'll send you news" or somesuch.  What's a simple/elegant way to collect those email addresses (assuming a standard LAMP stack)?  In particular, I'd like recommendations on

1. Javascript to handle the UI (complain if invalid email address, say thanks when they hit enter, etc).
2. CSS to make it look decent.
3. PHP to actually collect the email addresses and store them (either flat file or database is fine).

Or if there's a fancy Rails or AJAX way to do this, I'm very open to that, too.

(All I know currently is how to do this the old-school CGI way, with a plain html web form with a submit button and a server-side script that takes the form contents, pulls out the email address, and spits out html (potentially a redirect back to the original page).)

If I'm naive in thinking I can grab something off the shelf for this and should be starting with something like an AJAX tutorial, let me know that as well.  I've seen [this JQuery/AJAX tutorial](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-in-jquery-8-05-11/page1.html) recommended.  Is that or something like it the quickest way to get a simple sign-up form up and running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just implemented something like this on one of my websites strangely enough.  I didn't store the email addresses though, I emailed them to myself.  I'll comment that bit out so  you can write your flat-file or database storage bits.

Here's my implementation, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  Steal away :)

**In the HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').disabled = true;
    var val = $('#emailAddress')[0].value;
    $('#emailResponse').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" border="0" />').css('backgroundColor', 'ffffd0');
    $.getJSON('notify.php',{email: val}, function(data){
        if (!data.result) {
            $('#emailResponse').html(data.message).css('backgroundColor','ff9999').effect('highlight', {color: '#ffff99'}, 1000);
        } else {
            $('#emailResponse').html(data.message).css('backgroundColor','99ff99').effect('highlight', {color: '#ffff99'}, 1000);
        }
        });
            $('#btnSubmit').disabled = false;
            return false;
    });
$('#emailAddress').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#btnSubmit').click();
    }
    return false;
});
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin:0 auto;background:#ffffd0;width:500px;padding:10px;text-align:center; font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; border:1px solid black;">
    If you would like to be notified when we launch, please leave your email address here.<br /><br />
    <input type="text" id="emailAddress" size="40" style="border:1px solid gray;padding:5px;"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" style="padding:5px;" />
    <div style="padding:10px;margin:10px;" id="emailResponse"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

**In the notify.php file:**

```
<?php
$q = html_entity_decode($_GET["email"]);

$response = array();

if (!filter_var($q, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $response['result'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid email given - try again';
}
else
{
    // write to file or database

    $response['result'] = 1;
    $response['message'] = "Thanks, your details have been added, we'll notify you when we launch!";
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**Edit:** I know it's not pretty - inline styles, `<br/>` tags, etc.

Comment: +1 good starting point for him... Disect away, follow my JSON link to understand why the PHP is echo()'ing what it is.

Comment: Definitely - good point from Alex, don't follow this blindly cutting and pasting - make sure you understand what it's trying to do.  It should definitely help you next time.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was piecing it together using the tutorial linked to in the question but this was great to see it all put together like this.  Very helpful.  I went ahead and stole it pretty much verbatim (not totally blindly!), appending the email addresses to a flat file.  http://centmail.net

Answer (score 4):

Here is a regex that will validate 99% of emails

```
/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i
```

It looks a bit cryptic, but it works! As [Damovisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77546/damovisa) stated in the comments, it is easier to use PHP's `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` function.

Note if you are validating the email before you send it to PHP (for an ultra speedy validation), you will need to use a regex as there are no built in functions inside JavaScript to do this for you.

If you do use AJAX, you should have it return a success or error report using [JSON](http://json.org/).

The [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library can help you out a lot when using AJAX, but it's still important to understand how it works.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote has something to do with my Regex which some may deem too long and cyrptic? I didn't write it.

Comment: possibly because the filter_var($q, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) in php is easier? Remember, using regex means you now have two problems (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html) :)

Comment: Only 2 problems if you don't already having a working regex. I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the only function is for the users to enter an email address, I see no reason to bother with AJAX. It's not as if a page refresh is going to break the workflow of your users. Stick with the plain old CGI way of doing it.

Comment: +1 ... please don't use AJAX for the sake of it.

Comment: I agree to an extent - if AJAX fits your site design and behaviour though, I'd say use it.  Not everything needs to be purely about functionality - we'd have some pretty ugly sites out there if it was.

Comment: functionality doesn't *have* to be ugly... otherwise google would be ugly as hell :)
you could even argue that functionality allows for beautiful, but beautiful doesn't necessarily allows for functionality

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find something like "include this and everything will work magically", but you can have it ready in no time with a standard LAMP + jQuery implementation:

- UI: using regex you can easily validate e-mails. Google for that and you'll find tons of scripts.
- AJAX: jQuery AJAX methods are great, so I'd recommend that.
- With PHP is pretty easy to fetch your AJAX'd parameters and insert into the DB.