# How to update a web page without reloading the web page using AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to update info that a users entered in to a mysql database using php without reloading the web page how can I do this an example or tutorials will be nice.

If there is a tutorial on how to do this can you please share with me the link or links to the tutorial(s).

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice Ajax tutorial [here](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/), and it does use PHP on the server side. Once you do fully understand how Ajax works, by the way, you may probably want to move to a Javascript framework that makes it easier, such as [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax), [dojo](http://dojocampus.org/content/2008/03/14/functional-ajax-with-dojo/) or Google's [Closure](http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/11/17/goog-net-xhrio-make-simple-ajax-calls-with-google-closure/).

Answer (score 1):

This question is about taking an email address from a user, adding it to a database (or otherwise processing it with php), and updating the web page without reloading the page, ajax style:

[Javascript/css/php/mysql to collect user email addresses in a div on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699577/javascript-css-php-mysql)

The answer to that question should provide a good template for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The [W3Schools Ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Pull jQuery in to your project and look at its get/post methods documentation.